# Value undefeind

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="date"  id ="date1">
    <input type="date"  id ="date2">
    <button onclick="DisplayDates()">Result</button>
     <p id = "DifferenceInDays"></p>


  <script>

      // To set two dates to two variables
      var date1 = document.getElementById("date1").value;
      var date2 = document.getElementById("date2").value;

  // To calculate the difference of two dates
  var DifferenceInDays = date2.getdate() - date1.getdate();


// To display the final no. of days (result)
function DisplayDates() {
  document.getElementById("DifferenceInDays").innerHTML = DifferenceInDays;

}

  </script>
</html>
```

Hello guys, i am trying to calculate how many days are between 2 dates and I keep getting a return value of undefind? I just want to see how many days are between the 2 dates anything else like time is not importent. I was shown a diffrent question that is simialr but it dosnet help i dont know why when i subtract one date from the other that i get undefeind.

Comment: Unfortunately, the question is closed because of "duplication" but that link above isn't fully answering Patrick Ryan's question. As you already know, you should get values from inputs inside the function that is executed by a browser when a click event happens. But you also should check every command you've coded when you're debugging something. In this particular case you can `console.log()` those values you've got and you will see that they are strings. And then you try to call a method `getdate()` of strings but it belongs to a `Date` object. You can research more about this object

Answer (score 0):

this way:

```js
const
  el_date1   = document.getElementById('date1') 
, el_date2   = document.getElementById('date2') 
, el_dateDif = document.querySelector('#DifferenceInDays > span')
, OneDay     = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // 1 day in milliseconds
  ;

function DisplayDates() // calculate and  display  the difference of two dates
  {
  el_dateDif.textContent = Math.abs(el_date1.valueAsDate - el_date2.valueAsDate)
                         / OneDay;
  }
```

```html
<input type="date" id="date1">
<input type="date" id="date2">
<button onclick="DisplayDates()">Result</button>
<p id="DifferenceInDays"> difference : <span>...</span> days(s) </p>
```

Comment: tried it like this i get  -86400000 when i try to calculate between today and tomorow.

Comment: yes that is correct, it is a value in milliseconds, do you ever read the documentation?


@PatrickRyan see update...